# FIX: mysqldump: Couldn't execute '/*!80000 SET SESSION information_schema_stats_expiry=0 */

Tags: mysql, backup, restore, mysql-5.7, mysqldump

I've already asked this question in the "Stack overflow" website.
I don't understand why they closed my question even if I didn't get a working solution for my setup.

**Why did I submit it?**

1. I'm working on a project and I've been installing what's suggested on every guide on the internet (so every piece of working software was updated) and my problem was not solvable
2. In the future or in the present there are many users that will may experience what I've been experiencing.

**My original question to Stack Overflow:**

I'm not a programmer but I'm good at understanding things related to coding. I spent an entire day working on this. There is no fix aviable in any meaning around the web, so now I'm trying the last possible thing.

WHAT I HAVE TO DO: I have a mysql database and I want to do a backup. I really want to work with the terminal (I'm in MacOS) and try to avoid any software. Although, I have MySqlWorkBench. I tried to back it up using this string:

```
mysqldump -u user -p dbname > trial.sql
```

It should work perfectly. But.. this is the error I cannot fix

```
Couldn't execute '/*!80000 SET SESSION information_schema_stats_expiry=0 */': Unknown system variable 'information_schema_stats_expiry' (1193)
```

So, after 1 day, I finally decided to try it with WorkBench... and.. magic! Same error!

```
Couldn't execute '/*!80000 SET SESSION information_schema_stats_expiry=0 */': Unknown system variable 'information_schema_stats_expiry' (1193)
```

**After some research, I came to this conclusion:**

*"mysqldump" is a command, but firstly if you have installed mysql correctly, it works like an ".exe" kind of. It is finally clear that inside che file there is this*

```
information_schema_stats_expiry
```

that is giving errors.

I tried to:

Work it around with some flags starting from

```
mysqldump -u user -p dbname > trial.sql
```

but nothing worked for me.

I tried to export the DB with BENCHMARK but it prints the SAME VERY SAME error. So I couldn't be the problem...
Maybe the problem is this "information_schema_stats_expiry" and I tried to cancel it, like not having the script to run it.
Nothing worked.

Now I'm trying the last thing.

I firstly installed THE VERY LAST AVIABLE MYSQL VERSION (it was something like 8.0.2) to work with my stuff. Maybe the "information_schema_stats_expiry" is not there in the older versions? I found this info around. So with "brew" in the terminal I unistalled the MYSQL 8.0.2 and now if installing an older one, I think its like 5.6 or something. Meanwhile writing this, the computer is still installing MYSQL.
If everything fixes... Im sure me and many, many, many other guys will be happy about this. Cheers.

**Solution for this problem**

As mentioned, I was downgrading my MYSQL version to an older one.
After the installation process with "brew", maybe the installer did update me to another version.

I followed this guide and worked for me:[press here](https://medium.com/macoclock/setup-mysql-in-a-specific-version-on-macos-35d8ad89c699)

Now if I type in the terminal

```
brew info mysql
```

This is what's coming out:
mysql: stable 8.3.0

I was having hard problems EXPORTING A MYSQL DATABASE with "stable 8.2.0"

Now everything works fine.
Thanks for considering this post. I hope I've been helpful.
*If there are some good and experienced programmers around, I'd like to know what was going wrong with my earlier setup.*

Edo

Comment: It's unclear which version you are using. At one point, you say it's "something like 8.0.2", and at other points you seem to say you're using 5.6, or 8.2.0, or 8.3.0. Please run this query: `SELECT @@version;` and show what it responds.

Comment: Thanks @BillKarwin for the follow up! Glad for your interest.
I did run this query:
"SELECT @@version;". This is the result given: "8.0.2-dmr". 

With this version my problem is fixed and everything is working as it should.
My very big concern was about the fact me having everything very up to date and this very easy task was not working... I was starting to go mad. ;)

Comment: @EdoMeloni have you read this [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=101245) ? It talks about  mysqldump version mismatch

Comment: Given that 8.0.2 was a beta released in 2017, you are definitely not up to date. I suggest you should upgrade to the current stable version, which is 8.0.36 as we write this. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/ for a list of 8.0.x releases. The 8.2.0 and 8.3.0 versions are development branches, so they are less stable. I'd avoid them for now.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friends. With your help now I'm more aware of the databases and MySQL environments.

Comment: @ErgestBasha yes I did catch it, but I didn't find any practical or pragmatical solution to my problem.